# PKCS11 format key using Java keytool

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, keytool, pkcs#11

I want to get a server certificate for Tomcat 7 in PKCS#11 format. I used Java `keytool` utility and generated `.keystore` file using the following command

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

But I don't know which format is `.keystore`. I need PKCS#11. Can you explain me how to do this?

Comment: Be aware of which tags are followed. I just stumbled upon this question by clicking explicitly on cryptography related tags that are not often visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS#11 is *not* a certificate format. PKCS#11 is a C-level interface to access secure tokens. There is the Java PKCS#11 provider, which [*can* be configured for `keytool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#KeyToolJarSigner). Normally the keystore is in `"JKS"` (Java KeyStore) format.